# Need to insert XML tags based on conditions

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dynamic-reports

I am trying to insert few nodes to my XML file, based on few conditions.

This is my XML

```
<root>
<child name="abc">
<child name="xyz">

</root>
```

So now my condition is somthing like this ..

```
if(root/child[name="xyz"]) insert child2  under that tag
```

So my final XML should look like this

```
<root>
<child name="abc">
<child name="xyz">
<child2></child2>

</root>
```

Need programmatic help to achieve this.

Comment: use domDocument-> createelement

Comment: Your XML is not well formed.  Please fix.  (Add closing tags for the first two `child` elements -- there are multiple ways you might want to do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string xml = @"<root>
    <child name='abc'></child>
    <child name='xyz'></child>
</root>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);  //replace with xml file path
doc.Root
    .Elements("child")
    .Single(c => (string) c.Attribute("name") == "xyz")
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("child2", ""));

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

returns

```
<root>
   <child name="abc"></child>
   <child name="xyz"></child>
   <child2></child2>
</root>
```